# Query to select all sites states for site monitoring software

Tags: sql, t-sql

I writing a program for monitoring states of large number sites (more than 400). Information about site state (UP or DOWN) I receive from API. I use MS SQL Server to store information about states.

I have a SQL table named SiteStatus (id, site_name, site_status, date_time, iteration_counter).

Each time when site state are change I write a record with incremental iteration_counter.

How I can query all last states for all site_names? 
The goal - receive a table with site name, his state (UP or DOWN), date_time when it happens and iteration_counter number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the right indexes, the best solution is often a correlated subquery:

```
select sn.*
from sitenames sn
where sn.iteration_counter = (select max(sn2.iteration_counter)
                              from sitenames sn2
                              where sn2.sitename = sn.sitename
                             );
```

The right index is on `sitenames(sitename, iteration_counter)`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need !

Comment: Wouldn't `sitenames(sitename, iteration_counter desc)` improve the performance of `max`?

Comment: @HABO . . . That is am interesting question.  In theory, the index could be used to seek directly to the highest value for each `sitename` without finding the first value for the `sitename`.  I don't know if SQL Server does this, and this behavior may vary among databases.